# Mobile site not resizing correctly but fine on pc

Tags: android, html, ios, css, responsive-design

I'm building a site for a client http://www.patsybeautyclinic.co.nz (I'm a novice at html so go easy). It's fully responsive on pc but when loading it on android and ios it isn't as successful, it's almost as the media query isn't loading properly? (I have "meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" in my head tags)

I hate how I can't provide more specifics but I'm lost and have been stuck on this for awhile. Hopefully I have missed something simple so I don't waste anyones time...thanks in advance.

Here is what my s3 sees on the home page. (sorry it's so big)
[image]

Comment: Im using chromes inspector and the site looks fine to me.. maybe center the content but other then that whats wrong ?

Comment: I'll upload a screenshot to what my s3 is seeing on the home page.

Comment: Could you check and ensure your browser is up-to-date when viewing on your phone, i'm on my samsung s3 and it looks good.

Comment: I'm going to presume that's why it's not working on my s3 (I'm unable to update it). Just updated my ipod touch but the issue is still there. My friend also told me it's working on his andoird...so frustrating working with all these devices :p